# Substrate private beta site does not show up in the Google search engine

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, beta, search

It seems that the **substrate.stackexchange.com** website **does not** show up anywhere in Google search results when searching for "substrate stack exchange", "substrate stackexchange" etc.

Currently the main metric that is lacking for the private beta is site traffic, at least according to:

area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126136/substrate

Even the guidelines acknowledge that most traffic should eventually come from the search engines:

> Eventually, 90% of a site's traffic should come from search engines.

Currently the first 3 Google search results are the following (I checked on multiple devices and regions) and the private beta site **does not** show up anywhere on the first 5 pages:

[image: Google search results]

Could this be due to misconfiguration on the stackexchange side?

It would help a lot if something can be done to get the site be visible in the Google search engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site is showing up now. Just needed some time to be indexed properly (we didn't make any changes).

Comment: Good to know - though the question was asked when the site was in **private** beta, so now that it's in **public** beta I would assume that is what made the difference.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'd expect that much link juice in a month or two. It takes time for `trust` to build up though presumably being a subdomain of stackexchange.com helps a fair bit.

It seems like the main page gets indexed but none of the questions come up - E.g. `substrate stack exchange weight benchmark` you would expect google to get some choice answers from that. I guess that just takes time and will happen should it progress to a public beta.

Comment: Now that we are in public beta, I ran this search query on several search engines - "How can I transfer assets using XCM?" on different search engines and I saw results from SE on the following search engines - Bing, DuckDuckGo, Yahoo!, but none on Google.